# What is the scope of a variable defined in the source file, but outside of any function definition?

Tags: c++, scope

```
// Foo.cpp

int whatScopeAmI = 0;

Foo::Foo() {
 // source code
}
```

What scope does the variable `whatScopeAmI` have?

Comment: What you should be asking about is _linkage_, not scope.

Comment: It's global. it can be accessed from any linked source file as `extern int whatScopAmI;`

Comment: @ildjarn: Both questions make sense

Comment: @David : Both make sense, but one is more relevant than the other IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a global, available everywhere in the program.

If a different translation unit had a `extern int whatScopeAmI;` declaration, it would refer to the same variable.

If the variable was declared as `static int whatScopeAmI = 0;` it would have internal linkeage, and would be available only in the current translation unit.

Comment: @CoryKlein the implementation file (usually `.cc` or `.cpp`) plus all included headers. Basically, each cpp represents a separate translation unit.

Comment: @CoryKlein *each cpp represents a separate translation unit* ... unless you `#include` one cpp file in another. A translation unit is better defined as the (temporary) file created as a result of preprocessing, it is the file from which a compiler will create an object file.

Comment: @CoryKlein don't include cpp files, unless you know exactly what you're up against.

Answer (score 3):

That variable is a [global variable](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/) with *program scope* because it is defined out of any block:

> Variables declared outside of a block are called global variables. Global variables have program scope, which means they can be accessed everywhere in the program, and they are only destroyed when the program ends.

Comment: -1 I believe that quote is wrong. You can define a `static` outside of an execution block, and the variable isn't global.

Comment: I don't see the word static anywhere in this declaration: `int whatScopeAmI = 0;`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore A static var requires the `static` keyword. No such thing in the topic's code.

Comment: @JimR I know there's no static there, but the statement "Variables declared outside of a block are called global variables. Global variables have program scope" is wrong.

Comment: @s3rius see my previous comment.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Disagreed.  It is not wrong, it is incomplete.  It did however, answer the question.

Comment: @JimR it's wrong. It's just logic - "Variables declared outside of a block are called global variables. Global variables have program scope" - this implies all variables declared outside of a block are globals and have program scope, which doesn't hold for static variables. Logic 101.